# Convert time format: 5h00 to 5:00

Tags: excel, time

So my problem is i copy paste an agenda in excel with time in a format like 9h20. I want to convert it into 9:20 but i can't find the way to do it.
Just changing format doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h",":"))
```

and format as `Time`